# Getting args from kprobe not finding regs->rdi x86_64

Tags: linux, kernel, kprobe

I'm writing a kernel module under Scientific Linux 6.3 x86_64 and I'm looking to use kprobes. In this module, I need access to the first argument of a function on return, so jprobes are out.

I found this very helpful post: [Getting function arguments using kprobes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563635/getting-function-arguments-using-kprobes)

However, when I try accessing `regs->rdi` inside my probe, the compiler complains with

```
error: ‘struct pt_regs’ has no member named ‘rdi’
```

During my module initialization, I run this check with no problems:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_X86_64
 printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: this module only supports x86_64!\n");
 return -EINVAL;
#endif
```

Is there anything else I should be looking at?
`uname -r` returns `2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64.debug`

Here is a MWE:

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/blkdev.h>

static int kprobe_test(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs) {
  printk(KERN_INFO "rdi: %p\n", regs->rdi);
  return 0;
}

static struct kprobe myprobe = {
  .pre_handler = NULL,
  .post_handler = kprobe_test,
  .fault_handler = NULL,
  .addr = (kprobe_opcode_t *) generic_make_request,
};

int init_module(void) {
  register_kprobe(&myprobe);
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
  unregister_kprobe(&myprobe);
}
```

Which results in:

```
...
/home/user/kmod/kprobe_64_mwe/kprobe_mwe.c:7: error: ‘struct pt_regs’ has no member named ‘rdi’
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of `pt_reg` changes when `__KERNEL__` is defined.  Try using `di` instead.

Comment: Got it, I was looking through ptrace.h and that never really came to mind. Many thanks!